# when i hit play button more then once in my mp3 player my application crashes

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, crash

This is fragment activity and i have created a player to play online mp3 it works fine when i hit play button first time and i start the audio and if i pause it pauses.

**Problem** is when i hit play button more then once application crashes. please help

```
public class ListenFragment extends Fragment {
    final String url[] = {
            "HTTP://counterexample"};

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_listen, container, false);

        ImageButton btn_play = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        ImageButton btn_pause = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        btn_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer.pause();

            }
        });

        btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(url[0]));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

here is log cat, please review and answer.

Comment: What error are you getting. Can you post your error log here.

Comment: logs posted, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caution: You must either catch or pass IllegalArgumentException and
>   IOException when using setDataSource(), because the file you are
>   referencing might not exist.

Here is the thing. You must catch `IllegalArgumentException` too because the file you're trying to load might not be in existence since you're getting it from an online server. Replace your code with the following:

```
   btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(url[0]));
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Furthermore, I don't know why you're using string array instead of normal string. Read more

---

**UPDATE**
You can show notification in your app bar when the music has started playing using below snippet:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()){
                        //Show notification if music have started play
                        showNotif(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                }
            }
        });


     public void showNotif(Context context, String CHANNEL_ID){
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bubble_notif)
                    .setContentTitle("New Item Remind!")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notif_msg, reminder.getNumberOfItems()))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

            createNotificationChannel(context);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        }


        private void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
            // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
            // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                CharSequence name = "CHANEL_NAME";
                String description = "CHANNEL_DESC";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                channel.setDescription(description);
                // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
                // or other notification behaviors after this
                NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
```

More on displaying notification in status bar [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

Comment: i'm using string array because otherwise i can't stream this link live. please help improving this

Comment: First, If the answer solved the problem, accept it. I'd refactor the code for you later.

Comment: not solved :(
now app crashes on real device but runs fine on virtual device. please help

Comment: i can paste link to that question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135022/my-application-crashes-after-showing-the-splash-screen-on-a-real-device-but-not

Comment: Kindly help @DevMike

Comment: problem was in the media player and the way i used the pause button, now i made it and improved the code and now it runs good.

Comment: can you help me showing notification of that mp3 in status bar when it plays?

Comment: Yes. I can't post codes in the comment section. So I'll share a link to one of my open source project where i use the notification api. Here it is. https://github.com/devmike01/ItemsReminder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/oluwagbenga/reminder/views/utils/AlarmReceiver.java.

Comment: Also, I have updated my answer with what you requested for @SmartoDev

Comment: You are really great and helpful <3

Comment: I'm glad my answer helps.