# My application crashes after showing the splash screen on a real device, but not on a virtual one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created an application with Android Studio, never change a single word in any file.

When trying to run it on real device I got the following error:
following is `logcat`. please help solving this problem!

Android Studio - on Real device application crashes after splash screen but not on Virtual device

LOg

Comment: real device and emulator have many differences, such as memory, without codes, the question is too broadly to answer

Comment: Have you tried your app on another real device?

Comment: Turn OFF `Instant Run` and then after `clean` and `Rebuild`

Comment: Instant Run is turned off still the same crash @RahulChokshi

Comment: yes i've tried on my note 4 but it crashes after showing splash screen. but on virtual device it don't show splash screen but app run ok @Anatolii

Comment: @navylover kindly help me fix my app, i'll be thankfull i have putted alot in my app.

Comment: did you `restart`, `clean` and `rebuild` project

Comment: @RahulChokshi yes i did the same you instructed

Comment: @Smarto Dev You're posting the wrong log. Run the app again on your physical device and post the error log here. Hint: Most error logs often start with: `java.lang.xxxxxException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo`.

Comment: LogCat updated please review again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your log lots of frames is skipping when application is running. So maybe you should profile your GPU and see where is the problem from.
Here are some links that maybe helpful :

[Meaning of Choreographer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat)

[inspect GPU rendering speed and overdraw](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering)

and it will be helpful if you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ListView in android Api < 4.1 and you can't prevent it i think, just try to remove lines that use `lookForSelectablePosition` or you can increase `minSdkVersion`

Comment: i haven't used list view